Time Series Decomposition Justification
Problem's background.
There is the Wold's theorem saying that any covariance-stationary stochastic process can be written as a sum of the infinite-order moving average model and deterministic component, that is random but completely determined as a linear combination of its past values.
It is a theorem, in the sense that it can be proved and the proof can be found in the book by Brockwell and Davis, "Time Series: Theory and Methods".
However, I noticed that it is very common to use the following fact:
A time series $\{Y_t\}_{t \in T}$ can be written as
$$Y(t) =  Y_{\text{stationary}} + f_{\text{trend}}(t) + f_{\text{periodic}}(t) + \epsilon(t)\, ,$$

$Y_{\text{stationary}}$ is a weakly stationary process with
$\mathbb{E}[Y_{\text{stationary}}] = 0$;

$f_{\text{trend}}$ is a trend component, modeled as a deterministic
low degree polynomial, i.e. $f_{\text {trend}}(t)\sim \sum _ k c_ kt^
   k$;

$f_{\text {periodic}}(t)$ is the periodic component, modeled as a
deterministic, finite sum of harmonics, i.e. $f_{\text {periodic}}(t)
   \sim \sum _ k a_ k \sin (\theta _ k t)+ b_ k \cos (\theta _ k t)$.

$\epsilon (t)$ is white noise, i.e. $\epsilon (t)$ are i.i.d. across
all $t$ with expectation $\mathbb E[\epsilon (t)]=0$ and variance
$\mathbb E[(\epsilon (t)^2]=\sigma (t)$, and independent of the other
components.


There are various ways to express this, and while Wikipedia uses a different form, I prefer to stick with this one since it matches the form I encountered in my notes. I will refer to this decomposition as "Time Series Decomposition".
Question.
Can the Time Series Decomposition be proved or at least stated as a theorem, with explicitly provided limitations on it? I was surprised that I could not find any references to the proof of it.
I also do not understand its connection with the Wold's theorem, because here in the right-hand side we have possibly non-stationary part $f_{\text{trend}}(t) + f_{\text{periodic}}(t)$, and my investigations shows that there is no any assumptions about the stationarity of $Y(t)$. At first, I thought it should be a corollary of the Wold's theorem, but now it seems to me that this theorem is actually a specific case of a more general fact.
I guess even if it is a rule of thumb there should be formal mathematical reasoning behind it. Any help would be appreciated.
